# How can I use GWT Regular Expressions to extract text?

Tags: regex, gwt

Regular Expressions kick my pants every time I try to use them.  I'm using GWT's RegExp, and I want to extract two values from the following text:

```
Token[cc8ikjw2-fa7b-4cd6-b6677-04b723ef41 , 2ac7ce11-14b2-4de4-bm51-c22f23ea23af]
```

I want to pick out the two codes and assign them to variables while ignoring the 'Token[' characters.

Please help me. You are my only hope.

Comment: And what have you done so far?

Comment: Reviewed the Regular Expression Cheat Sheets, Examples, and stared into space.

Comment: Main question: Why do you think you need regex? You know that old saying about regex and problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a quick solution here (obviously may not work if there are wild variations to the string format, but works for the provided example):

```
    RegExp pattern = RegExp.compile( "Token\\[(\\S*)\\s*,\\s*(\\S*)\\]" );
    MatchResult result =
        pattern.exec( "Token[cc8ikjw2-fa7b-4cd6-b6677-04b723ef41 , 2ac7ce11-14b2-4de4-bm51-c22f23ea23af]" );
    String token1 = result.getGroup( 1 );
    String token2 = result.getGroup( 2 );
```

The actual regular expression to match the tokens in given example is: `Token\[(\S*)\s*,\s*(\S*)\]`, but obviously you need to escape all back slashes in a Java string.

Comment: Works like stink on a dog. Thanks!